# What is the easiest way to add country auto-complete and city auto-completewith jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, geolocation

I'm looking for the easiest way to add
1. auto complete field to country.
2. auto complete field to city.

i search the web and found few bad examples,
i don't mind to use txt file (but please provide one if you recommend on) or free web service.

Please the [GeoNames](http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?name_startsWith=Chic&country=US) doesn't support cities, but only countries.
the maxmind only supply the csv, but the code is missing.(http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite)

Comment: How about the google places API: https://developers.google.com/places/ ? Don't know if its free...

Comment: Since when did Geonames not support cities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need flexible solution when

1. You need database with names like from Maxmind
2. You need search engine with autocomplete support like at IndexDen see http://indexden.com/documentation/tutorial-autocomplete